# Ion-Segment in Ionic4 vs Ionic3

Tags: ionic3, ionic4, ion-segment

I have a segment of the form given below in **`Ionic3`** and the code given below. Could any one please tell me how to implement the same in **`Ionic4`**.

### Ionic3 code

```
    <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-buttons left>
      <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle="user-menu">
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="doLogout()">
        <ion-icon name="ios-log-out" color="primary"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
  <div text-center (click)="editProfile()">
    <img class="user-avatar" src="assets/imgs/avatar.svg" />
  </div>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="category" color="primary">
      <ion-segment-button value="official">
        Official Info
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="personal">
        Personal Info
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <div [ngSwitch]="category">
    <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'personal'">
      <ion-item>
        <h4>First Name</h4>
        <p>X</p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <h4>Last Name</h4>
        <p>YZ</p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <h4>Phone No</h4>
        <p>(541) 754-3010</p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <h4>Address</h4>
        <p>XYZ 711-2880 Nulla St. Mankato Mississippi 96522</p>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'official'">
      <ion-item>
        <h4>User Id</h4>
        <p>Xyz</p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <h4>Email</h4>
        <p>Xyz@abc.com</p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <h4>Employer</h4>
        <p>Amazon</p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <h4>Company Name</h4>
        <p>Amazon India</p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <h4>Company Id</h4>
        <p>{{nowDate|date:'hh:mm:a'}}</p>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

[image]

### Ionic 4 code

```
    <ion-toolbar>
  <ion-segment (ionChange)="segmentChanged($event)">
    <ion-segment-button value="camera">
      <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="bookmark">
      <ion-icon name="bookmark"></ion-icon>
    </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
</ion-toolbar>
```

In the Ionic4 officeial documentation they mention only about creating the segment buttons and didnt specify how to populate list based on that. Is it similar to **`Ionic3`** using `*ngSwitchCase`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can continue using the `*ngSwitch` as before, what you have to do is in the event `(ionChange)="segmentChanged($event)"` change the value you want to show as you used to do with `[(ngModel)]="category"`.

Add this method in component:

```
segmentChanged(event) {
  this.category = event;
}
```

"event" is the value of the case that you have put in the `ion-segment-button value="camera"`.

More information: https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitchCase

Comment: Actually event parameter is not the value assigned to the ion-segment-button tag, but an object with info about the change event. The actual value is located on event.detail.value.